# Fluent Validation C# obsolete

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have a problem with a fluent validation command line, currently the library marks the execution line as obsolete.

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add<ValidationFilter>()).AddFluentValidation(options => options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()));
```

I send a custom response with the errors detected in the fluent validation but when trying to change the line so that it is not marked as obsolete the validations do not work, I have tried as follows

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add<ValidationFilter>());
services.AddFluentValidationNjsm(Configuration);

public static IServiceCollection AddFluentValidationNjsm(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<entity1Validator>();
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<entity2Validato>();
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<entity3Validator>();
        return services;
     }
```

I'm importing the method from a service collection extension, that's why it looks like a separate method.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had no choice but to create a file that contains fluent validation for each entity created following the standard on the official page

https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#getting-started